# What happens when the token under an android profile in InTune expires?

Tags: android, microsoft-intune

Using the Coreporate-owned dedicated devices enrollment profile we created a profile and enrolled devices using it. Now we come back to add more devices and the profile and token have expired. What happens to all the devices associated with this profile? Do they need to be re-enrolled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/enrollment/android-dedicated-devices-fully-managed-enroll

"Replacing or revoking a token/QR code won't have any effect on devices that are already enrolled."